# How to load page from SD card and still show live data from sensors?

Tags: programming, library

I am just wondering, how can we display page from SD card and still show live data from sensors?

I have web server running on Arduino mega using ethernet shield, in my sketch I am doing client.print to build content of a page being displayed, and [refreshing](http://san.gotdns.ch:8090) it display live data.

But I can't think of a way how can I load page from SD card and display data from sensors.

Comment: Can you show your code please? It very much depends on how you're doing it.

Comment: @MarkSmith http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/149563/22943

Comment: Is your problem really that you want your device to serve two different web pages?  Or are you trying to embed your live data into the middle of a pre-formed page? Or something else?

Comment: I want to embed live data onto a pre formed page.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt understand you, the above link I pasted is just how I am loading page from without sd card .

Comment: Sorry, I'm typing on a phone. Do you know how to load a file from the SD card into memory?

Comment: Use a character that you are not using (e.g. `@`) and place that where you want to put the live data. Then, when reading the file forward all characters other than '@' to client.print, but when you find a '@' print the live data. Very rudimentary templating.

Comment: Maybe combine JavaScript with Arduino-Websockets. But it would be more logical tot connecties your arduino to a more capable server.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon [this W3C example](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) you can have `w3-include-HTML.js` file with the following contents:

```cpp
function w3IncludeHTML() {
  var z, i, a, file, xhttp;
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    if (z[i].getAttribute("w3-include-html")) {
      a = z[i].cloneNode(false);
      file = z[i].getAttribute("w3-include-html");
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          a.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          a.innerHTML = this.responseText;
          z[i].parentNode.replaceChild(a, z[i]);
          w3IncludeHTML();
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      return;
    }
  }
```

Now you can put this in your `.html` file:

```html
<div w3-include-html="generated_data.html"></div>
<script src="w3-include-HTML.js"></script>
```

and then you can use something as:

```cpp
server.on("/generated_data.html", live_data);
```

If you want to be able to use `server.on()` you must include `<ESP8266WebServer.h>` but you can serve the content the way you like. You can examine the [`ESP8266WebServer::on()` method source code](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/src/ESP8266WebServer.cpp) and adapt it according to your needs or you can just use that method as is.

Everything until now will result with calling the `live_data()` function and inserting it's response into the `div` which has the attribute `w3-include-html="generated_data.html"`.

Now you only need to generate the live data inside the `live_data()` and to send the response:

```cpp
void live_data() {
  String data_from_sensor;

  // read here the data from some sensor and store it in data_from_sensor
  String response = "<h1>Live data</h1><p>The data is: " + data_from_sensor + "some unit</p>";
  server.send(200, "text/html", response);
}
```

And that's it. The live data generated inside `live_data()` will show where was the empty `div` with `w3-include-html` attribute.

Of course, you can have more `div`s with different `w3-include-html` attributes and belonging `server.on()` statements.

There are many ways, this is just an example so you can get an idea from where to start. This code will not update the live data on and on but now that you know the mechanism, you can modify the code to do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on Chupo_cro’s answer... His suggestion to use
`XMLHttpRequest()` is definitely the way to go. But unlike his answer, I
suggest here to *not* send HTML-formatted data. Just send the raw data
as [JSON](http://json.org/), which is the simplest data format suitable
for this job. Since your client computer is likely to be orders of
magnitude more powerful than your server, you can offload all the job of
presenting the data to the client JavaScript code. Keep your Arduino
server minimalist and have it only serve:

- static content (HTML, JavaScript and CSS) from the SD card
- *raw* live data as JSON.

And then let the client handle the presentation of the data in whatever
form you like.

Your static Web page would then contain no data and have instead
placeholders of the form `<span id="XXX">---</span>`. For example:

```html
<p>Rain sensor reading: <span id="rainValue">---</span>,
<span id="rainQuality">---</span> rain<br>
Temperature: <span id="tempCelsius">---</span> °C
/ <span id="tempFahrenheit">---</span> °F<br>
Humidity: <span id="humidity">---</span>%<br>
Dew point: <span id="dewPoint">---</span> °C</p>
```

Your client JavaScript code starts by collecting references to those
placeholders:

```javascript
// HTML elements with replaceable content.
var elements = null;

window.onload = function() {
    var getElt = document.getElementById.bind(document);
    elements = {
        rainValue: getElt("rainValue"),
        rainQuality: getElt("rainQuality"),
        tempCelsius: getElt("tempCelsius"),
        tempFahrenheit: getElt("tempFahrenheit"),
        humidity: getElt("humidity"),
        dewPoint: getElt("dewPoint")
    };
    setInterval(requestLiveData, 5000);
};
```

Then the page can be updated from live data simply by filling the
`innerHTML` attributes of the elements:

```javascript
function dewPoint(temperature, humidity) {
    return ...;
}

// Update page from live data.
function updatePage(data) {
    elements.rainValue.innerHTML = data.rain;
    elements.rainQuality.innerHTML =
        data.rain < 300 ? "heavy" :
        data.rain < 500 ? "moderate" : "no";
    elements.tempCelsius.innerHTML = data.temperature;
    elements.tempFahrenheit.innerHTML = data.temperature * 9 / 5 + 32;
    elements.humidity.innerHTML = data.humidity;
    elements.dewPoint.innerHTML = dewPoint(data.temperature, data.humidity);
}
```

Notice that the data processing (Celsius → Fahrenheit conversion, dew
point calculation, converting the rain reading to words) is now done by
the client. The live data is retrieved from the server using Ajax, aka
`XMLHttpRequest()`:

```javascript
function requestLiveData() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState != 4) return;
        if (request.status != 200) {
            alert("Ajax request failed: "
                + "status = " + request.status);
            return;
        }
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        updatePage(data);
    };
    request.open("GET", "/live_data");
    request.send(null);
}
```

You may have noticed the last line of the `window.onload` function is

```javascript
setInterval(requestLiveData, 5000);
```

which means the `requestLiveData` function above will be automatically
called every 5000 ms.

Now, the only thing your server has to do is answer a request for
`GET /live_data` by sending the raw data as "application/json". It
should look like this:

```javascript
{"temperature":15,"humidity":48.3,"rain":500,"soilMoisture":22}
```